# getting address of particular instruction in a function

Tags: c

I want to acquire the address of `label1` in function main without calling function `Func(int a,int b)`. How can this be done?

Code:

**File1.c**

```
int *ptr2;
int Func(int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a+b;
    label1:
    ptr = (int*)&&label1;
    return c;
}
```

**File2.c**

```
#include<File1.c>
extern int *ptr2; 
int main()
{
    int *ptr,var;
    //var = Func(10,20);
    ptr = ptr2; 
}
```

Comment: There is no portable way of doing this (indeed, `&&` is a [compiler-specific language extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)).  Why do you need to?

Comment: i want to get the address of a label so that i can find the size of a function. By placing a label at the end of function and then subtracting it with address given to start of a function.

Comment: @perreal  yes you are right i want to find the length of function in bytes